# JavaScript: как присвоить значение переменной, если она не была до этого объявлена?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в JavaScript создать переменную с помощью условия, если она не была до этого объявлена?

Например:

```
if(!a){
     a = 'test';
 }
```

В этом случае ошибка в консоле `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Comment: `if (typeof a == 'undefined')`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почему не ответом? :-)

Comment: А еще можно просто объявить переменную :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо! А можно в условие написать сразу для группы, т.е. заменить конструкцию if (typeof a == 'undefined'  || typeof b == 'undefined' || typeof c == 'undefined' ) на что-то более изящное?

Comment: А я бы сказал "нужно" :)

Comment: @Pavel, а какую задачу в итоге ты пытаешься так решить?

Comment: @Grundy, Сложный вопрос) Вкратце, приходит блок html кода от сервера с input cheked данными. Мне нужно присвоить переменным определенные значения. Переменных в этом случае нет. Но они есть, если поочередно кликать на каждый input.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но суть его другая. Я сначала подумал про то с чем сам постоянно мучаюсь - нельзя в JS так вот сделать `if (var a = 1){ alert(1);}` поэтому не плюс.

Comment: напиши так : if(a==undefined){var a = 'test';}

Comment: @Dimon вот я и спросил об этом, почему он не знает. А PHP вот знает!)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, Спасибо вам за минус) Но ваш код вызывает ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: @Pavel может создать чат? Что-то уже много написано, а по делу маловато

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так не будет работать :-) ошибка будет на уровне вызова функции :-) при попытке взять значение для параметра

Comment: @Pavel, стоит все-таки добавить в вопрос _конкретную_ задачу. Для текущей постановки - достаточно просто _объявить_ переменную.

Comment: @Pavel Павел, ну вы совсем не вчитываетесь - спрашивете одно "как в JavaScript создать переменную с помощью условия" и это правда фича, которой в JS нет, и которой активно пользуются в других языках - кинул код который не работает, а хотелось бы. А сами вы хотели спросить про то "как проверить переменную на существование".

Comment: @Grundy угу .убрал

Comment: @pavel Почему вы не хотите просто объявить переменную заранее? Если у вас чекбоксов заранее неизвестное количество, то их состояние лучше вообще не в отдельные переменные складывать, а в массив или объект.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(this.a);
if(!('a' in this)) { 
  this.a = 'test';
}
console.log(this.a);
```

> если она не была до этого объявлена

А если объявлена, но не присвоена?

Answer (score -2):

Напиши так : 
`if(a==undefined){
    var a = 'test';
}`

Я неправильно написал в комментарии и удалил тот комментарий. Фишка в том, что **перед** выполнением кода интерпретатор пробегается по коду предварительно для того, чтобы сформировать **объект-контекст выполнения** кода, **наполнить** его. в данном случае этот объект-контекст называется *Global*, так как код глобальный. Касательно переменных, то сначала переменным, **объявленным через *var***, присваивается значение *undefined*, а потом в процессе обработки кода эти значения меняются на то, что в коде стоит (*"test"*). Если посмотреть на твой код

```
if(!a){
 a = 'test';
```

}

, то интерпретатор не увидел *var* слева от *a = 'test'*; и не занес в объект-контекст *Global* объект переменных (*VO*) с переменной *a* внутри него. Все переменные предварительно заносятся в объект переменных (*VO - variable object*) как *undefined*, если интерпретатор "увидел" перед ними *var*.

Вот статья неплохая есть про объект-контекст выполнения кода http://corporate.tuenti.com/en/dev/blog/functions-and-execution-contexts-in-javascript-2

Я тебе плюс ставлю, чтобы минус тот перекрыть)))

Comment: @Pavel - блин. минус опять поставили тебе. второй перекрыть не могу). прикалывается народ. я смотрю, разозлился народ из-за миох шуток. минусы строчит). мне пофиг на минусы).

Comment: при использовании `a==undefined` будет исключение _Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined_ при не объявленной  переменной _a_,  А использовать _var_ внутри _if_ бессмысленно, проще объявить переменную до использования.

Comment: @Grundy - у меня этот код отработал в хроме без ошибок. если написать так, как я написал, то сначала (ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛЬНО) переменная "а" занесется в объект переменных VO (который находится в объекте-контексте Global) как undefined, сравнение (а==undefined) даст тру и переменной а присвоится строка "test". если же перед условием поставить, например, var a=10; , то "test" не присвоится.

Comment: а если `var a;` то присвоится

Comment: правильно. вы тоже какой-нибудь вариант предложите. я не знаю, как можно обойти тот момент, что переменная обязательно должна быть засунута в объект переменных перед выполнением кода.